# Error '!dat' AvAudioPlayer

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, ios4

I'm getting no sound and this error when I build ( Error '!dat' trying to set the (null) audio devices' sample rate). is something wrong with the music file or is it the code.

```
NSString *playM = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"wildM" ofType:@"m4a"]; 

NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:playM]; 

player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];    

[player prepareToPlay];
player.currentTime = 0;    
[player play];
```

Comment: Did you get this figured out. I just started getting this. Audio and video were working fine, then put them in SVN and pulled them down on another Mac and got this error. I tried replacing the audio and video with the versions on the mac where it still works but still get the error.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Here is what I did:

- Close xcode and the iOS simulator
- Unplug the headphone jack and any usb headphones you might have
- Restart xcode and run your simulation (problem should be solved)
- Plug back in any audio devices you want to use

Answer (score 0):

Code looks ok.  You don't have to call prepareToPlay, that just buffers things... nor do you need to set currentTime.  More than likely your m4a file is incorrectly encoded.